# Does "ex-urban" exist or have I made it up?

Tags: single-word-requests, titles

I'm looking for a word that implies that people are moving out of cities: is *ex-urban* a word? I found it in the Urban Dictionary but that definition is not at all what I mean. I can't find it anywhere else. Below is what I would like to use as part of the title for my dissertation but I can't figure out how to say what I mean in a way that's grammatically correct:

> U.S. [EX-URBAN?] MIGRATION OF LGBTQ+ POPULATIONS AND THEIR NEED FOR CULTURALLY-COMPETENT SUBURBAN HEALTH CARE PROVIDERS

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Note that the so-called Urban DIctionary is a crowdsourced collection of current slang, and not a reliable reference. In fact, *exurban* already has an [established usage](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exurban) in public policy, at least in the U.S. For terminology requests, furthermore, subject-matter experts are probably a more reliable source than "language experts" as on this Stack. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help], as well as our guidance on [tag:single-word-requests].

Comment: Thanks!  :)  But from a language expert perspective, is there a word that you might recommend instead of "ex-urban" that would allow me to communicate what I mean - "out of city" - in my dissertation title?

Comment: I would like to ask if the hyphen is necessary in “culturally-competent” and further, if that is a reference to doctors/providers who are more aware of or compassionate for alternative populations/groups?

Comment: Hi P. Smith!  :)  The hyphen is commonly used there in the literature. I would say that the term refers to health care providers who understand that different populations experience different challenges related to health care access and health outcomes.  For example, studies show that the mortality rate for lesbians from breast cancer is much higher than it is for women in the general population.  It’s important for providers to create a welcoming clinical setting, so lesbian patients will be more likely to disclose; and to understand how health risks may differ for lesbians.

Answer (score 1):

What you might have seen before is *extra-urban,* but that usually means "outside the city" positionally rather than implying movement out of the city. Thus "extra-urban migration" is not movement out of the city, but movement around it, within the area which is not city.

As choster has commented, it's entirely possibly that *ex-urban* does have the connotation you want, as jargon; I'm not certain from a language perspective that *ex-* implies movement out of something.

Comment: _Ex-_ does mean precisely ‘out of’ or ‘away from’, though generally without the hyphen and only with Latinate or Greek roots (expatriate, etc.); with the hyphen, it means ‘former’ (ex-girlfriend, etc.). _Exurban_ is not a word I’ve seen before, but as an adjective I would intuitively understand it to mean ‘away from the city’. _Ex-urban_ I would understand to mean ‘formerly urban’.

Comment: Thanks, Janus!  :)  That’s how I would understand the term as well.  Maybe I’ll try “exurban” and see if my committee goes for it!

Answer (score 0):

An [exurb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exurb) is urban development beyond a large city and its suburbs which may have fewer employment opportunities but the amenities of "bedroom communities."

Exurbs may once have been small sleepy towns before being swallowed up in sprawl. In 1990, [McKinney, Texas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/McKinney,_Texas), some 32 miles north of Dallas, had a population of some 21K, 2016 estimate, 172K.

If thwre are exurbs, then there is an adjective exurban.

Comment: Thank you - this is what I also found but it's not what I mean.  If you have a recommendation for a word that means "out of city" and that seems appropriate given my dissertation title, above, then I would be most appreciative.

Comment: non-urban? how far out in the boonies are these folks moving?